# Have an Excel workbook POST itself to a webservice: how to get bytes?

Tags: web-services, vba, http, excel

I'm writing an Excel macro to post a workbook to an HTTP webservice. I'm looking at using `ServerXMLHTTP`:

```
Sub PostSelf()
    Dim URL, objHTTP
    Set objHTTP = CreateObject("MSXML2.ServerXMLHTTP")
    URL = "http://someService/"
    objHTTP.Open "POST", URL, False
    objHTTP.setRequestHeader "User-Agent", "Mozilla/4.0 (compatible; MSIE 6.0; Windows NT 5.0)"
    objHTTP.send ("")
End Sub
```

According to [the docs](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms755436(v=vs.85).aspx), "[the send] method takes one optional parameter, which is the requestBody to use. The acceptable VARIANT input types are BSTR, SAFEARRAY of UI1 (unsigned bytes)."

Assuming that the workbook is saved, how can I retrieve the bytes of the workbook as a SAFEARRAY of UI1?

Comment: Would this help? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356118/vba-ws-toolkit-how-to-get-current-file-as-byte-array

Comment: @DavidZemens Thanks, nice find, that worked perfectly.

Answer (score 1):

```
With CreateObject("ADODB.Stream")
    .Type = 1 ' Binary stream
    .Open
    .LoadFromFile ThisWorkbook.FullName
    .Position = 0
    arrBuffer = .Read ' get the whole binary
    MsgBox TypeName(arrBuffer) ' Byte()
    MsgBox .Size ' Length in bytes
End With
```

**UPD:** Binary mode Stream instance [`.Write` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms675017(v=vs.85).aspx) gets Variant data type parameter that contains an array of bytes, [`.Read` method](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/ms676702(v=vs.85).aspx) output data type is the same, this method just converts result to [Variant data type](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/gg251448(v=office.15).aspx) to provide flexibility and compatibility, and the resulting varible will contain array of bytes - `Bytes()` - due to implicit type conversion, we are using VB not C after all.

Comment: I tried this, but got an exception running `.LoadFromFile ThisWorkbook.FullName` (although it worked on another workbook).