# How to read binary content of an embeded word object

Tags: vba, ms-word, ole

I have an embedded OLE object in word as "InlineShape". I would like to access this object as a data stream / string. at the moment, I can see some ideas for Excel via OLEObject, but it seems that there is no solution for Word that I can see.

Comment: Put it on the Clipboard and access it from there; copy/paste to somewhere that can manipulate it; read out the Word Open XML and work from the base64 representation in that; save it as a picture to a file and work with the file...

Comment: @Cindy InlineShape.OLEFormat doesn’t have a copy method unfortunately. The picture bit might work.

Comment: Ah, but InlineShape.Range *does* have a Copy method and will copy the picture.

Comment: @CindyMeister thanks, i managed to concoct something as per below

Answer (score 0):

The following code achieves what I want:

```
' from here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1356118/vba-ws-toolkit-how-to-get-current-file-as-byte-array
Public Function GetFileBytes(ByVal path As String) As Byte()
    Dim lngFileNum As Long
    Dim bytRtnVal() As Byte
    lngFileNum = FreeFile
    If LenB(Dir(path)) Then ''// Does file exist?
        Open path For Binary Access Read As lngFileNum
        ReDim bytRtnVal(LOF(lngFileNum) - 1&) As Byte
        Get lngFileNum, , bytRtnVal
        Close lngFileNum
    Else
        Err.Raise 53
    End If
    GetFileBytes = bytRtnVal
    Erase bytRtnVal
End Function



Sub TestMe()
    Dim shapeIndex As Integer: shapeIndex = 1
    Dim ns As Object
    Dim folderItem
    Const namePrefix = "site-visit-v2.5"
    Const nameSuffix = ".dat"

    Dim fileBytes() As Byte
    Dim tempDir As String: tempDir = Environ("TEMP")
    ' first embedded Item - you may need adjust if you have more shapes
    ActiveDocument.InlineShapes.Item(shapeIndex).Range.Copy

    ' paste it to temp dir
    Set ns = CreateObject("Shell.Application").namespace((tempDir))
    ns.Self.InvokeVerb ("Paste")

    ' find the file now
    Dim Item As Object
    Dim rightItem As Object
    Set rightItem = Nothing
    ' find the file that was pasted
    ' because when files are pasted and name exists, you could get a name such as "site-visit-v2.5 (10).dat"
    ' we pick the most recent that matches
    For Each Item In ns.Items
        If Item.Name Like namePrefix & "*" & nameSuffix Then
            If rightItem Is Nothing Then
                Set rightItem = Item
            Else
                If Item.modifyDate > rightItem.modifyDate Then 'a more recent date is found
                Set rightItem = Item
                End If
            End If
        End If
    Next
    fileBytes = GetFileBytes(tempDir & "\" & rightItem.Name)
    MsgBox "Read " & UBound(fileBytes) + 1 & " bytes"
End Sub
```